# java 8 stream how to map 2 column into the map

Tags: java, java-stream, java-collections-api

I have a table:

> name | data | num
>   item1 | 16 | 2
>   item2 | 17 | 3
>   item1 | 16 | 5

I would like to transform it to:

> { item1: {16+16, 2+5}, item2: {17, 3}}

However I only succeed to produce the following result:

> { item1: 16+16, item2: 17}

with the following code:
The Stats class store both fields, but I don't know how to add both fields into the data

```
class Stats {
    public Integer data, num;
    public Stats(Integer td, Integer nf) {
        data = td;
        num = nf;
    }
    public Integer getdata(){
        return data;
    }
    public Integer getnum(){
        return num;
    }
}
Map<String, Stats> map = new HashMap<>();
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(table));
map = lines.map(x -> 
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                z -> z[0],
                z -> Integer.parseInt(z[1]),
                (a, b) -> a+b));
```

The above code only works for `Map<String, Int>` since I'm not sure how to make `Map<String, Stats>` works.
Any idea how to get the item on the second column into the map while and using 1 pipeline only?

Comment: You can't store two integers inside a value of type Integer. Create a class containing a field data and a field num.

Comment: I tried to create a class call ClassA with contain both fields but i don't know how to call it! i don't know the correct syntax for it. I will revise the question now .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                z -> z[0],
                z -> Integer.parseInt(z[1]) ::Integer.parseInt(z[1]) ,
                (a, b) -> a+b));

Comment: What is the type of `z`?

Comment: Type of Z is String. I got {item1=32, item2=17} using Map<String, Int>

Comment: Do you literally mean the String "16+16" or do you want the sum ie 32?

Comment: Yes, i want to sum them use to 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation that:

- doesn't need any extra classes
- works for any length of numeric values (not just 2)
- is (technically) just one line

```
Stream<String> lines = Stream.of("item1,16,2",
      "item2,17,3",
      "item1,16,5"); // sample input

Map<String, List<Integer>> map = lines.map(s -> s.split(","))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0],
      a -> Arrays.asList(a).stream()
       .skip(1).map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()),
      (a, b) -> {for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
          a.set(i, a.get(i) + b.get(i)); return a;}));
```

Printing the map after running this outputs:

```
{item2=[17, 3], item1=[32, 7]}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/JnG6NL) of this code.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create a class containing two integers:

```
public final class TwoInts {
    private final int data;
    private final int num;

    public TwoInts(int data, int num) { 
        this.data = data;
        this.num = num;
    }

    // getters omitted for brevity
}
```

Then you can reuse the logic you already have, except instead of using integers, you'll use TwoInts instances. So you'll need to be able to add two instances of TwoInts together to produce another TwoInts instance (just like you're producing a new integer by adding two integers):

```
public final class TwoInts {
    private final int data;
    private final int num;

    public TwoInts(int data, int num) { 
        this.data = data;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public static TwoInts sum(TwoInts first, TwoInts second) {
        return new TwoInts(first.data + second.data, 
                           first.num + second.num);
    }

    // getters omitted for brevity
}
```

And there you go:

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(table));
Map<String, TwoInts> map = 
    lines.map(line -> toArrayOfStrings(line))
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
              row -> row[0],
              row -> new TwoInts(Integer.parseInt(row[1]), Integer.parseInt(row[2])),
              (a, b) -> TwoInts.sum(a, b));
```

Comment: What is `row[0]`? `row` is a `String`.

Comment: Given the code of the OP, it's not a String. It's an array of Strings.

Comment: I'm talking about your code. `lines` is a `Stream<String>`. Therefore in your code `row` is a `String`. The OP's code needs clarification.

Comment: OK, right. I assumed the OP's code did compile and didn't care much about the stream. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

First you can make your Stats class a little more reduce-friendly adding merge method (I also prettified it a little):

```
class Stats {
    final int data, num;

    public Stats() {
        data = num = 0;
    }

    public Stats(int data, int num) {
        this.data = data;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public Stats merge(Stats stats) {
        return new Stats(this.data+stats.data, this.num+stats.num);
    }

    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public int getNum(){
        return num;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + data + "," + num + "}";
    }
}
```

Now you can solve your task using the chain of Collectors. Suppose your input comes from String stream like in Bohemian answer:

```
Stream<String> lines = Stream.of("item1,16,2",
          "item2,17,3",
          "item1,16,5"); // sample input
```

Now the resulting map can be built in this manner:

```
Map<String, Stats> map = lines.map(s -> s.split(",")).collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], 
    Collectors.mapping(a -> new Stats(Integer.parseInt(a[1]), Integer.parseInt(a[2])), 
    Collectors.reducing(new Stats(), Stats::merge))));
System.out.println(map);
```

Live demo is [here](https://ideone.com/Ar0Ccg).